# Borrowing a property's value from state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I don't know if I worded this right, so bear with me. Basically, I have a component that is a functioning counter (increments or decrements). The other component is a timer that counts down from (by default) 25 to 0.

Previously, I had the timer just set to the value of 25, but I am trying to have **the timer change as the value of the counter changes**, and when the use presses the "start" button, **the timer will count down from whatever number was set by the counter**.

I can get the components working individually, but not together.
I've tried setting `this.state.currentCount` to the value of `this.props.time`, and then changing the value of `this.state.currentCount`, but no luck. Either the timer doesn't budge or it doesn't reflect the value of the counter.

Not sure if I should be using `componentWillReceiveProps` instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. There's a screenshot at the bottom if that helps at all.

Session Component:

```
const Session = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      minutes: 25,
      seconds: 0
    };
  },

  increment: function() {
    this.setState({ minutes: this.state.minutes + 1 });
  },

  decrement: function() {
    this.setState({ minutes: this.state.minutes - 1 });
  },

  timeToString: function(time) {
    return time + ':00';
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <section>
        <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
        {this.state.minutes}
        <Clock time={this.state.minutes}/>
      </section>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = Session;
```

Clock Component:

```
const Clock = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return { currentCount: this.props.time };
  },

  startTimer: function() {
    var intervalId = setInterval(this.timer, 1000);
    this.setState({ intervalId: intervalId });
  },

  pauseTimer: function() {
    clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
    this.setState({ intervalId: this.props.time });
  },

  timer: function() {
    var newCount = this.state.currentCount - 1;
    if (newCount >= 0) {
      this.setState({ currentCount: newCount });
    } else {
      clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <section>
        <button onClick={this.startTimer}>Start</button>
        <button onClick={this.pauseTimer}>Pause</button>
        {this.props.time}
        <br></br>
        {this.state.currentCount}
      </section>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = Clock;
```

[image]

Comment: Js-fiddle would be awesome

Comment: I've been trying to figure that out. Getting all the parts of react working in JSfiddle is harder than it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getInitialState` only runs when the component is first initialized so on next
updates from the parent component it won't run that function.  You are correct
in that you want to use one of the lifecycle events and in this case
`componentWillReceiveProps` sounds like the most appropriate because you can
`setState` there and you don't need to wait for the component to render (otherwise
you would use `componentDidUpdate`).

I haven't checked this code but I think it should work with this addition:

```
const Clock = React.createClass({

    ...

    componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
        // Perhaps pause timer here as well?
        this.setState({
            currentCount: nextProps.time
        })
    },

    ...

});
```

Comment: I had a feeling one of those would do it, but I'm still pretty new to how the lifecycles in React work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

because your timer depends on `Start` button. it would be good if you set state of `currentCount` in `startTimer` method.

```
startTimer: function() {
  if(this.state.intervalId)
   clearInterval(this.state.intervalId); //clear the running interval

  this.setState({ currentCount: this.props.time }); // reset currentcount
  var intervalId = setInterval(this.timer, 1000);
  this.setState({ intervalId: intervalId });
},
```